# Installing ubuntu on a non activated version of windows

Tags: 12.10

My version of windows 8 isn't activated and I want to install ubuntu, from a USB-stick. When I'm in the install setup it asks me to select my operating system, but I don't have one, so it says it will clear the whole drive. What exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu installer does not see any operating system(s) on your hard disc(s) so it will advice to format the disc (wipe the disc and format it to ext4 if you choose ext4) and then to use the whole disc to install Ubuntu.

Only if you want to save anything that is currently on the disc you might want to back that up; but as you said: there is not OS yet.

So nothing to worry about :)